# Undefined error with db:migrates when deploying with capistrano

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, migration, capistrano

When I try `cap deploy:cold`, everything is ok, but on this stage:

```
 ** transaction: commit
  * 2013-10-25 18:36:38 executing `deploy:migrate'
  * executing "cd /home/test_app_deployer/apps/mini_reader/releases/20131025143548 && bundle exec rake RAILS_ENV=production  db:migrate"
```

I have error:

```
rake aborted!
 ** [out :: 81.218.92.235] FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "test_app_deployer"
 ** [out :: 81.218.92.235] FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "test_app_deployer"
 ** [out :: 81.218.92.235] /home/test_app_deployer/apps/mini_reader/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.14/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:1222:in `initialize'
```

`failed: "rvm_path=$HOME/.rvm $HOME/.rvm/bin/rvm-shell '1.9.3' -c 'cd /home/test_app_deployer/apps/mini_reader/releases/20131025143548 && bundle exec rake RAILS_ENV=production  db:migrate'"`

This my **deploy.rb** file:

```
require "bundler/capistrano"
require "rvm/capistrano"

server "ip", :web, :app, :db, primary: true

set :application, "mini_reader"
set :domain, "reader.alma.by"
set :user, "test_app_deployer"
set :deploy_to, "/home/#{user}/apps/#{application}"
set :deploy_via, :remote_cache
set :use_sudo, false
set :port, "222"
set :rvm_ruby_string, '1.9.3'
set :rails_env, "production"


set :scm, 'git'
set :repository, "git@github.com:user/app.git"
set :branch, "master"

default_run_options[:pty] = true
ssh_options[:forward_agent] = true

after "deploy", "deploy:cleanup" # keep only the last 5 releases

namespace :deploy do
  %w[start stop restart].each do |command|
    desc "#{command} unicorn server"
    task command, roles: :app, except: {no_release: true} do
      run "/etc/init.d/unicorn_#{application} #{command}"
    end
  end

  task :setup_config, roles: :app do
    sudo "ln -nfs #{current_path}/config/nginx.conf /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/#{application}"
    sudo "ln -nfs #{current_path}/config/unicorn_init.sh /etc/init.d/unicorn_#{application}"
    run "mkdir -p #{shared_path}/config"
    put File.read("config/database.example.yml"), "#{shared_path}/config/database.yml"
    puts "Now edit the config files in #{shared_path}."
  end

  after "deploy:setup", "deploy:setup_config"

  task :symlink_config, roles: :app do
    run "ln -nfs #{shared_path}/config/database.yml #{release_path}/config/database.yml"
  end

  after "deploy:finalize_update", "deploy:symlink_config"

  desc "Make sure local git is in sync with remote."

  task :check_revision, roles: :web do
    unless `git rev-parse HEAD` == `git rev-parse origin/master`
      puts "WARNING: HEAD is not the same as origin/master"
      puts "Run `git push` to sync changes."
      exit
    end
  end
  before "deploy", "deploy:check_revision"
end
namespace :imagemagick do
  desc "Install the latest release of ImageMagick and the MagickWand Dev Library"
  task :install, roles: :app do
    run "#{sudo} apt-get -y update"
    run "#{sudo} apt-get -y install imagemagick libmagickwand-dev"
  end
  after "deploy:install", "imagemagick:install"
end
```

And after `cap deploy:setup` there is **database.yml** file in /apps/app_name/shared/config directory. I've created user and database with postgres, and add this in this file(**database.yml**), it's looks like:

```
production:
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: utf8
  reconnect: false
  database: reader_production
  pool: 5
  host: localhost
  user: user_name
  password: user_pass
```

### **UPDATE**

I've removed database.example.yml file from git repository and added some instructions in **deploy.rb** file:

```
before "deploy:setup", :db
after "deploy:update_code", "db:symlink"

namespace :db do
  desc "create database.yml in shared dir"

  task :default do
    db_config = ERB.new <<-EOF
production:
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: utf8
  reconnect: false
  database: db_production
  pool: 5
  host: localhost
  user: username
  password: pass
    EOF

    run "mkdir -p #{shared_path}/config"
    put db_config.result, "#{shared_path}/config/database.yml"
  end
```

I've checke that it created database.yml file in current directory with right instruction, but I still have error: 
`FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "test_app_deployer`
Why rails ignoring database.yml file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thiss mistake was, because I use `user` in database.yml production settings instead `username` and it's uses default username of OS, that hadn't password in postgres settings

Answer (score 0):

The file `/apps/app_name/shared/config/database.yml` needs to be symlinked into `/apps/app_name/current/config/database.yml`, there are numerous Capistrano tasks to handle this, or simply check a production version of the `database.yml` into your own repository.

[Railscasts #133](http://railscasts.com/episodes/133-capistrano-tasks) lists a task (amongst others) for doing just this:

```
desc "Symlink shared configs and folders on each release."
task :symlink_shared do
    run "ln -nfs #{shared_path}/config/database.yml #{release_path}/config/database.yml"
    run "ln -nfs #{shared_path}/assets #{release_path}/public/assets"
end
```

That `:symlink_shared` task has to be called sometime, the best place to do it is:

```
after 'deploy:update_code', 'deploy:symlink_shared'
```

Comment: I haven't file `database.yml` in my repository, I've added it in gitignore, and have `database.example.yml`. File, that created in  `shared/config` directory is similar like `database.example.yml`, I've changed it accordingly with my postgres settings.

Comment: But if the database file is not symlinked from shared, into current, then as far as rails is concerned, there isn't one, so there is no DB config. I've updated my answer with more info from Railscasts.

Comment: I've tried your solution, but still have this error. It's right, but it doesn't work. I add some more information.